# How to locate DOM monster error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, duplicates, nodes

I used a highly respected program called DOM Monster to check my website [Taikuri Kim Wist](http://www.kimwist.com) for errors.

DOM tool gave me this error: *There is 1 duplicate id for nodes in your document. Node ids must be unique within the HTML document. See JavaScript console for details.*

The problem is, I have no clue how to locate this error. I know for sure that there is no duplicate id:s in html and should not be in JavaScript either.

Does anyone know how to actually locate these kinds of errors, because I would very much like to fix this asap.

Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `document.querySelectorAll("[id]")` in the console on your site shows all elements that currently have an id attribute. They are not even many enough that you'd need to search for the duplicates programmatically:

```
NodeList [
  <header id="header" class="header">,
  <div id="stuck_container">,
  <div id="stuck_container" class="isStuck" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; top: -60px; visibility: hidden;">,
  <div id="owl1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded" style="">,
  <footer id="footer" class="footer">,
  <a href="#" id="toTop" class="fa fa-angle-up" style="display: none;">
]
```

You can spot the dupe quickly :-)

Comment: Thanks Bergi,  that id "stuck_container" is the duplicate one and I found it on script.js file also. When I removed this part &&$("#stuck_container") from the script.js file, I lost a drop down menu in the navigation. I'm not sure how to fix this but I guess I have to change the id name in html first and try to work from there.